# SQLIte for Iphone: Records not getting updated

Tags: ios4, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I am using Appcelerator. I am using the following code to fetch db records. I am using an SQLite Client, NavCatLite as a SQLite GUI for viewing and Inserting Data. I am having a Weird issue that when I update a record via SQLite client, it does reflect in my code. Why is it not refreshing the data? I even closed the client as I thought it would be caching the connection but it did not help either. Code is given below:

```
/** * All Db Functions Goes here */

var resumeDB = Titanium.Database.install('resume.db', 'myResume');
//var resumeDB = Titanium.Database.open('cold');

//Iterate through ResultSet

var myResultSet = resumeDB.execute('SELECT * FROM cvs');
while (myResultSet.isValidRow())
{
  Ti.API.info("Result iS = "+myResultSet.fieldByName('sb_title'));
  myResultSet.next();

} // Do something that iterates

resumeDB.close();
```

P.s: This is not a Read-only Database. The user will be inserting and fetching Data every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The database file that you initally store in `/Resources` is not the database file that is used by the app post-install.

Per [the guide](http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Working+with+Local+Data#WorkingwithLocalData-SQLiteDatabases)

> On the other hand, **install() will copy
>   a pre-existing database file from
>   Titanium's Resources directory, or one
>   of its descendants, to
>   applicationDataDirectory/../databases/
>   and return a reference to the opened
>   database**. If a file already exists
>   with the same name, the copy action
>   will silently fail and the database
>   will simply be opened.

In short, it just doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 0):

I think the database is only installed once, along with the app when it is first installed onto the device/simulator (I've seen this with iPhone anyway, not sure about Android). The first time the app is run your database is copied to another location, and thereafter it's the copy that's run, not your updated database. Try deleting the contents of your build/iphone / build/android directories and running the app again to force an update. If that doesn't work, try resetting the simulator / deleting the application off the device and installing again.